# Simple Web Questionnaire

Tags: php, html, database, forms, redirect

I am making a website that  will tell the user if they need a certain document in their business transaction. I know how to make forms, but I want to be able to ask the question on one page, and if the answer is yes, it goes to the next question- if no a different question. Like this:

[image: Questionairre Flowchart]

Also in one of the questions, the user's name and other info are inputted. How can I hold onto that data and then put it on the correct document needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to hold onto the data from a user input, you could use something similar to: `localStorage.setItem("item-name", value);` or `sessionStorage.setItem("item-name", value);`
when the form is submitted where `value` is the data from the user input. The difference between the two is localStorage keeps the data past a session while sessionStorage keeps the data until the user session expires.
Finally, when the data needs to be retrieved, you can use `localStorage.getItem("item-name");` or `sessionStorage.getItem("item-name");`, depending on which one you used to store the data, and set the result in a variable to then be displayed in the final output.

I hope this helps you out!